# How to Highlight Specific Column Values based on a CSS Class and Binary Digit On/Off Positions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, oracle11g, oracle-apex

Using Oracle APEX v5.1.2.

Unsure how to tackle the following but I have a table called, **flag_defs** with the following example data:

```
ID      NAME
------- ------
1       A
2       B
3       C
4       D
5       E
6       F
```

Based on the above table, I need to display all these names with a report region but not on separate lines but in the following fashion:

```
A B C D
E F
```

where I'm only showing 4 names across.

Now based on the following binary convention, say the following:

```
010010
```

where the first 0 lines up to ID = 1 and the last 0 in this sequence lines up to ID = 6

Based on this binary sequence, which will be stored within a database field in another table, I need to apply a class called "flag-red" that I will define as color:red;font-weight:bold; to the names that have the ID position set to "1".

So in the above example binary sequence, both "B" and "E" only would receive the class of "flag-red" and would be red/bold within the report region. The others would not.

The same goes with removing the class if the digit "1" is reset back to "0" for that ID.

I would need to iterate through each digit in this field to set the correct class in my report.

I'm assuming I would firstly create a report and assign a span class to each name but unsure if this is the correct approach.

Furthermore, would JavaScript be a better option or stick to SQL

Would appreciate some assistance on how to tackle the above.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve. But the behavior you want is more like a UI part. So I would suggest go with Javascript way, that would be easier to toggle css classes.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to make a report in the following way:

Lets say you have a query which returns some rows with `rownum` column. Adding a pivot to this query we can turn it into the following:

```
select *
  from (select r, mod(rownum, 6) group_no, floor((rownum - 1)/6) row_id
          from (select rownum r
          from dual connect by level <= 30) t)
 pivot(max(r) for group_no in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0))
 order by 1
```

[image]

Now we can join this query with the table which stores binary mask to show. Lets say initial query has columns `C1`, `C2`, ... `C6`with data, and joined table with mask data has columns `M1`, `M2`, ... `M6`. (If it is one column with a mask, we can produce 6 columns using calculating expressions) You can calculate a name of a CSS class in these columns, something like

```
select ...
       case when <expression1> then 'flag-red' else 'flad-green' end M1,
       ...
```

Next step is to go to report properties, choose column `C1` in the column list, go to `Column formatting` section, put `#M1#` in the `CSS Classes field`:

[image]

Also, mark `M1`, `M2`, ... `M6` columns as hidden.